# How to enable TextField selection handlers with QtVirtualKeyboard on a QQuickWidget?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am integrating QtVirtualKeyboard in my QML app and this causes selection handlers to appear in text fields when some text is selected as shown below.

[image]

However the handlers are not draggable if I integrate my QML app using a QQuickWidget. Instead it prints out an error:
`QMetaObject::invokeMethod: No such method QQuickWidget::inputMethodQuery(Qt::InputMethodQuery,QVariant)`

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", "qtvirtualkeyboard");

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickWidget quickWidget;
    quickWidget.setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
    quickWidget.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    quickWidget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Page {
    TextField {
        selectByMouse: true
    }
}
```

The handlers work just fine if I use a QQuickView instead, by changing main.cpp like so:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", "qtvirtualkeyboard");

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickView quickView;
    quickView.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

    QWidget::createWindowContainer(&quickView)->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```