# How to hide selection handles on QtQuickControls2 TextField?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, qtvirtualkeyboard

I use `QtVirtualKeyboard` in my QML app and as a result selection handles appear whenever some text is selected in a `TextField`:

[image]

Is there any way to hide these handles? Nothing in [TextField](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textfield.html) or [TextInput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html) docs mention anything about this.

Comment: Is this the same as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65190871/how-to-enable-textfield-selection-handlers-with-qtvirtualkeyboard-on-a-qquickwid)?

Comment: @JarMan the previous question was asking how to make the handles work but since I can't seem to find an answer, I'm asking now how to remove them completely. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the handle by setting the InputMethodHint flag in the TextField to Qt.ImhNoTextHandles. That should get rid of the handle. ref https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for